# Is 85 minutes enough time to transfer in MCO from international flight?

Tags: international-travel, layovers, short-connections, mco

My international flight arrives in MCO (Orlando International) at 6:00 am. I must take another flight (MCO-JFK) at 7:25 am. Is that enough time to go through immigration, claim luggage and get to the boarding gate? I have already spent more than one hour in line for immigration at MCO, but I don't know if it is usual. If there is a long line, can I ask the officers to "skip" it?

Comment: Delta has four daily MCO-JFK flights, of which 7:29 is the first of the day. If you miss it, you won't likely be delayed for more than a few hours.

Comment: Specifying your nationality, type of visa/visa waiver/green card, and purpose of visit would be helpful in assessing the time to go through immigration, which is in most places notoriously longer for foreigners than for US passport holders. Also are you flying on the same airline, or airlines part of the same alliance? Are you ticketed through (single booking for both flights)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have a good probability to make it. Your flights are early in the morning so they are more likely to be on time and also the waiting time will be shorter in the checkpoints.

I would suggest you the following :
1/ Make yourself known by the company. If you have booked a complete itinerary with the same company, they will make what they can to make the connection happen as otherwise, they will be accountable to find a solution for you.

2/ If you see that the waiting queue is too long, check with the agents. Explain the situation with a smile and seek help from them. They will potentially direct you to the fast lane if any.

Good luck!